# Phone not downloading media in whatsapp, not getting connected to FB through App, email not syncing. Messages can be sent and read in whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp, email, sync

1. Phone not downloading media in WhatsApp
2. Not getting connected to Facebook through App, email not syncing.
3. Browsers are not connected to browse the Internet.
4. Messages can be sent and read in WhatsApp.

Happens in WiFi as well as data.

Comment: Is your internet connection working? Have you tested any other phone with your WiFi?Have you contacted your ISP?

Answer (score 1):

Whatsapp chatting service is free for the most of network providers when they don't allow media streaming (As per in your case). So the actual issue is that either your phone is not connecting to internet or you don't have permission to access internet( perhaps you don't have credit in your SIM ). For first issue you may try **Settings>Networks & wireless>Cellular & SIM** and set APN to default (if it is not set) and allow data roaming. Then check your connection by some of the native apps e.g. Store or Edge. If problem continues then please try reinstalling problematic apps.

**Note:** This is only for cellular connection.